# cpp_properties.json goes back to default every minute in vscode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, configuration, vscode-extensions

I have added some paths in the include path and they worked properly, but suddenly the json file went back to default :

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I have added back the paths and saved it, yet it went back to default after a minute.

I have found this answer: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/pull/5368/files

but I couldn't find the configuration.ts in the extension's folder on my computer.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: I'd suggest that you raise a new issue ticket in that repo. If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Yo i had the same error if u have Prettier installed uninstall/deactivate it.
worked for me